# How can I set automatic use of the double-oblique hyphen when a line break falls on an intentional hyphen?

Tags: fontspec, hyphenation, libertine, opentype

Say you've got a compound word in which the elements are conventionally joined with a hyphen, instead of being jammed together, like *fact-check* is and *gumshoe* isn't, or one of those fancy hyphenated last names, like Lloyd-Beeblebrox. In old-fashioned typography, if a line break occurred at the hyphen, the hyphen character at the end of the line would be replaced with something that looks like a short, slightly slanted version of an equal sign, known in Unicode (U+2E17) as a DOUBLE OBLIQUE HYPHEN. So, say I want to get all highfalutin and use this in a document, or a part of a document? Is there a way to tell LaTeX directly to do this? Or a package that will do that for me? Or is there maybe an OpenType feature that i can use (if provided for in the font) through a `fontspec` call? For context, I am using LuaLaTeX, with the `memoir` class, the `fontspec` package and the Linux Libertine O font (which includes the U+2E17 character) but without the `libertine` package.

Comment: Try adding `\preexhyphenchar"2E17` in your preamble.

Comment: @Marcel Krüger Please post that as an answer so I can credit you for it. Thank you. It works, and works as well (as I expected it would) when placed inside an environment definition in the preamble, since I only want to use it in some parts of the document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LuaTeX has a lot of parameters for hyphenation. The one we need here is `\preexhyphenchar` (`pre` because the DOUBLE OBLIQUE HYPHEN should be inserted before the break and `ex` for explicit because this should only add explicit hyohenation points [aka hyphens which also appear when no break occurs])

So we get

```
\documentclass{article}

% First some font setup
\DeclareFontFamily{TU}{libertine}{}
\DeclareFontShape{TU}{libertine}{m}{n}
  {<-> \UnicodeFontName{Linux Libertine O}{script=latn;}}{}

% The important command:
\preexhyphenchar"2E17

\begin{document}
% For demonstration purposes, we kindly ask TeX to insert lots of hyphens: (Never do this in a normal document!)
\pretolerance-1
\hyphenpenalty-1000
\exhyphenpenalty-1000

% Done. Now just add some text:
A detective was hired to do a fact-check.
A detective was hired to do a fact-check.
A detective was hired to do a fact-check.
A particularly skillful and talented detective was hired to do a fact-check.
\showoutput
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you try this with fontspec, things get a bit more complicated because fontspec has the habit of resetting LuaTeX's hyphen char parameters as often as possible. I don't think that there is any real reason for that, so you can work-around it by hiding the primitive parameter from fontspec:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}

% The important commands:
\let\realpreexhyphenchar\preexhyphenchar
\realpreexhyphenchar"2E17
\newcount\preexhyphenchar % Hide the primitive from fontspec
\begin{document}
% For demonstration purposes, we kindly ask TeX to insert lots of hyphens: (Never do this in a normal document!)
\pretolerance-1
\hyphenpenalty-1000
\exhyphenpenalty-1000

% Done. Now just add some text:
A \oldstylenums{detective} was hired to do a fact-check.
A detective was hired to do a fact-check.
A detective was hired to do a fact-check.
A particularly skillful and talented detective was hired to do a fact-check.
\showoutput
\end{document}
```

Comment: Or, I should say, it works when invoked within an environment definition, but at first only in the first block of text that I use that environment on. For a while I was able to fiddle with things in the vicinity of each subsequent instance and get it to work.

Comment: For instance, it didn't seem to like me using an environment that was using a different font, so I ended the first environment and restarted it after the intervening section was done, and then it worked again for a little; but it didn't seem to care when a different embedded environment with yet a different font came along. At another point it objected when I removed a ```\goodbreak``` even though it wasn't needed otherwise.

Comment: But eventually it just quit working altogether between one paragraph and the next with no other formatting besides a few ```\emph{}``` envirinments, a ```\thinthinspace``` (from the ```thinsp``` package) and an ```\ldots```.

Comment: In the end, I decided to try just putting it into the preamble outside of an environment definition, but then it wouldn't make any substitutions at all. This is a complex document with a number of fonts, few of which even have the U+2E17 character at all. So maybe that is the problem here.

Comment: I know that when using some primitives, you need to unlock something else, or protect it somehow, with other commands (I don't know the correct terminology). Might that be the case here?

Comment: @StonefeatherGrubbs Does your document use different languages?

Comment: No. Well, a little elvish, though not "officially."

Comment: @StonefeatherGrubbs I probably found your problem: You are using fontspec, right?

Comment: Yes. And Memoir.

Comment: That looks to have done it. Thank you!

Comment: For the benefit of others who come across this page, it should be noted that the ```\preexhyphenchar``` primitive is only available when using the LuaTeX engine; XeTeX doesn't have it.